# add delay to all celery tasks

Tags: python, celery

I'm using Celery (without Django) along with RabbitMQ for task management but I would like (if possible) to set Celery to execute one task every 20 minutes.

I know periodic tasks can be scheduled, but I would like *all* tasks submitted to enter the queue and then be processed in 20 minute cycles.

I'm assuming there will be a configuration option in the 'celeryconfig.py' file, but I can't see anything in the documentation that looks like it will help.

Is this possible, if not is there anything that you could recommend?

Comment: You mean like, execute one task from the queue every 20 minutes?

Comment: @Maciek yes exactly that, sorry if it wasn't very clear

Comment: I don't see anything like what you need in Celery configuration. Rate limits are applied only to tasks of the same type... Maybe write a decorator you'll use for every function that will make sure task execution takes at least 20 minutes and allow Celery to have only 1 worker?

Comment: Hmm yes thats a good option, I was just hoping there was a bit of the documentation I was missing! Thanks